# Return REST API response as CSV

Tags: apex, apexrest

Currently the API is giving data as JSON. How can I return data as CSV?

Data from response:

```
"[{\"id\":\"0012800000pNOVVAA4\",\"name\":\"GenePoint\"},
{\"id\":\"0012800000pNOVTAA4\",\"name\":\"United Oil & Gas, UK\"},
{\"id\":\"0012800000pNOVUAA4\",\"name\":\"United Oil & Gas, Singapore\"},
{\"id\":\"0012800000pNOVLAA4\",\"name\":\"Edge Communications\"},
{\"id\":\"0012800000pNOVMAA4\",\"name\":\"Burlington Textiles Corp of America\"},
{\"id\":\"0012800000pNOVNAA4\",\"name\":\"Pyramid Construction Inc.\"},
{\"id\":\"0012800000pNOVOAA4\",\"name\":\"Dickenson plc\"},
{\"id\":\"0012800000pNOVPAA4\",\"name\":\"Grand Hotels & Resorts Ltd\"},
{\"id\":\"0012800000pNOVRAA4\",\"name\":\"Express Logistics and Transport\"},
{\"id\":\"0012800000pNOVSAA4\",\"name\":\"University of Arizona\"},
{\"id\":\"0012800000pNOVQAA4\",\"name\":\"United Oil & Gas Corp.\"},
{\"id\":\"0012800000pNOVWAA4\",\"name\":\"sForce\"}]"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Wrapper Class and then you can traverse the list. Find the code-

```
public class CSVWrapper {
    public String id;
    public String name;
}


String response = '[{\"id\":\"0012800000pNOVVAA4\",\"name\":\"GenePoint\"}, {\"id\":\"0012800000pNOVTAA4\",\"name\":\"United Oil & Gas, UK\"}]';

public String responseToCSV(String response) {
    List<CSVWrapper> listWrapper = (List<CSVWrapper>)JSON.deserialize(response, List<CSVWrapper>.class);

    String csv = '';
    String COL_SEPARATOR = ',';
    String LINE_SEPARATOR = '\n';
    for (CSVWrapper cw: listWrapper) {
        csv += cw.id + COL_SEPARATOR + cw.name + LINE_SEPARATOR;
    }

    return csv.removeEnd(LINE_SEPARATOR);
}
```

Please change the COL_SEPARATOR and LINE_SEPARATOR according to your requirement.